# Search bar in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to select an item if there is only 1 result showing(see image 1). If there are 2 results, desired item can be selected(see image 2). It just proceeds to the next scenario which inputs the date. it inputs the dates in the search bar instead of the date field. but works perfectly when there are 2 results.

Image 1 
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R1ec.png)
Image 2
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmWco.png)

Here is my code:

```
java.util.List<WebElement> substituterlist = getDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='select2-drop']/ul/li"));
        int list = substituterlist.size();
        for (int i = 1; i <= list; i++) {
            WebElement subUser = getDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='select2-drop']/ul/li[" + i + "]/div"));
            String subUsername = subUser.getText();

            System.out.println(subUsername.indexOf("-"));
            String selectUsr = subUsername.substring(0, subUsername.indexOf("-") - 1);

            if (substituteUser.equals(selectUsr)) {
                waitForMoreTime(10);
                subUser.click();
```

Comment: have you checked the `list` value? Does your script go into the loop and through some error? What's the error trace message that you received?

Comment: my issue is that it cannot select if there is only 1 result, it just proceeds to the next scenario which inputs the date. it inputs the dates in the search bar instead of the date field. but works perfectly when there are 2 results.

Comment: no error trace message received.

Comment: Need more info. can you for  " (int i = 0; i <= list; i++) " , give i= 0  for "1 result" ...give us more info and we will help you.

Comment: I already added more in the code.